# Where is the list of name field [dialogflow API VoiceSelectionParams's name field]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I use google cloud dialogflow API.

I would like to set VoiceSelectionParams's name field.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.VoiceSelectionParams

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/api/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.VoiceSelectionParams.html

However, I can't find a list of name field anywhere.

I serched "dialogflow VoiceSelectionParams name" on the Internet, but I couldn't find any hint.

Could you give me any advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voices available for Dialogflow are the same ones as the ones for Cloud Text-to-Speech.

You can see a list of them [here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices).

Comment: Now, I understand. Thank you for your help!